# Oracle Redaction and Definer's Rights Stored Procedures

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, data-masking

0

I created a data **Redaction policy** for a field EMAIL in a Person Table in an ORACLE Data Base 12c.

In the expression statment of the Redaction Policy is the exception for the **Data base owner user**: This user can access the EMAIL field without redaction. It works perfectly :)

This field with redaction (EMAIL) is involved in a insert-select statmement in a trigger, so when the trigger is executed I get the error ORA-28081: Insufficient privileges - the command references a redacted object

To avoid this error, I moved the insert-select statement to a Stored Procedure that, by default, has Definer Rights, and the Definer is the **Data base owner user**. But I still have the ORA-28081 error.

Why this do not solve the error if the procedure is executed with the rights of the Data base owner user and the redaction has exception for this user?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "Data base owner user"; it would help if you provided the steps to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error ORA-28081 is removed with the grant Exempt Redaction.
In this case

```
GRANT EXEMPT REDACTION POLICY to Data_base_owner_user;
```